# Understanding Moonlight; Is it a framework?

Tags: moonlight

I'm trying to understand if moonlight is a framework which is similar yet independent to the mono framework in exactly the same way as silverlight is similar yet independent for dot net framework.

I'm trying to write a library that works for both moonlight and mono and I was wondering if I would need to target specific frameworks (as is the case with silverlight and dot net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moonlight uses the Mono runtime but, like Silverlight, uses a subset of the available .NET framework. So yes, you'll need to target different frameworks for desktop vs Moonlight (Moonlight uses the 2.1 profile, same as Silverlight).

Comment: So then technically, I can create a moonlight project just by targeting Silverlight itself

Comment: Correct, Moonlight is meant to run Silverlight Apps so targetting Silverlight is the right way to go.